# What does it mean (NetBeans, warning on compile)?

Tags: java, netbeans

> Warning text: "warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6"

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#seealso

> The `-source 1.6` option specifies that version 1.6 (or 6) of the Java programming language be used to compile `OldCode.java`. The option -target 1.6 option ensures that the generated class files will be compatible with 1.6 VMs. Note that in most cases, the value of the -target option is the value of the -source option; in this example, you can omit the -target option.
>   You must specify the -bootclasspath option to specify the correct version of the bootstrap classes (the `rt.jar` library). If not, the compiler generates a warning.

Comment: I simply compile the project in NetBeans 7.1 without additional arguments.

Comment: It's possible that you have multiple JDKs installed.. if you no longer need the older versions, you should uninstall them.

Comment: I have found a problem. In options NetBeans, in section "a source code Format" stood JDK 6. Thanks you for the help.